# How to save note onto Mac instead of iCloud on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: upgrade, high-sierra, notes.app

I recently upgraded to High Sierra 10.13.1. I can't save notes on my Mac, the only option is iCloud.

How can I save the note on my Mac instead of on iCloud?

Comment: Any reason for the yelling?  CAPS=YELLING.  Please consider editing this question to remove the CAPS, and expand on exactly what is happening.  What happens if you attempt to save a note to the Desktop for example.

Answer (score 2):

I think I can help you. You just need to enable the On My Mac account in Notes Preferences.

1. Open Notes Preferences

   [image: Open Preferences in Notes]
2. Check the Enable the On My Mac checkbox

   [image: enable on my Mac]
3. You should now see the On My Mac account in the Notes sidebar and can move notes there by dragging them or creating them from that location

   [image: on my Mac account in sidebar]